# Support Vector Machine Example

Tags: svm

Could anyone give me an Example in detail which show how SVM exactly work with all the necessary Mathematics?

As I tried to search in the internet and found very little example about SVM.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can watch the stanford lectures on machine learning from lectures 6 to 8. Its on youtube. It teaches you everything on SVM and the mathematics involved in SVM. Have a look at it..